# How do I get the filepath out of my code and into a insert statement for mysql?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, html

How do I get the filepath out of my code and into a insert statement for mysql?

```
     protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
            {
                OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=root; Password=commando;");
                cn.Open();
            }
            if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                                string fileuploadpath = Server.MapPath("~/userdata/" + theUserId + "/uploadedimage/");
                                FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Path.Combine(fileuploadpath, + filename)); 
//error on this line best overload method has some invalid arguements
                                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";

                                //some kind of function to take the path then enter it into my insert syntax?

                                OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO Pictures (UserID, picturepath) VALUES ('"+ theUserId +"' , '"+ fileuploadpath +"')", cn);
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }

                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;

                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/userdata/" + theUserId + "/uploadedimage/") + filename);
```

to

```
string fileuploadpath = Server.MapPath("~/userdata/" + theUserId + "/uploadedimage/");
FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Path.Combine(fileuploadpath ,  filename));
```

then fileuploadpath will be available for you to put in your query.

Of course, your question isn't very detailed. Did you want the local path from where the client had the file stored on their machine?

FYI: Use parameters instead of concatenation.

Comment: no not the local path just the mapPath I get an error on this line: FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Path.Combine(fileuploadpath, + filename)); (error in the brackets)

Comment: best overload method has some invalid arguements